# How to get all the values of a particular child from firebase using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my data structure

[image]
.

Now I want to get all the ids from this database.

In MySQL, I could easily get it using this simple query

```
SELECT id
From sensor_data
```

But in firebase, I don't know how to do it.

I've tried

```
firebase.database().ref('/sensor_data').once('value', function(
    snap.forEach(function(obj){
        var date = obj.val().date;
        var time = obj.val().time;
        var id = obj.val().id;
        var ph = obj.val().ph;
        var temp = obj.val().temp;
   })
});
```

But it needs another loop to separate the desired data.

Comment: I would read about best practices for structuring your data in firebase. For example, your data could be structured like so: /sensor_data/{id}. So, then if query sensor_data, you immediately have a list of ids which are objects that contain your other information.

Comment: Aside from Luke's comment on structuring the data, the code looks like it should work. What's the problem when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id, you can query it directly like so:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/sensor_data/{$id}`).once('value').then(snapshot => console.log(snapshot.val(), snapshot.val().id));
```

If that's not the case, you indeed need to get the collection and then iterate like you've done, or try it like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/sensor_data').once('value').then(data => {
  for(let record of data) {
    console.log(record.id);
  }
});
```